# facebook.dialog is failed using a facebook account with Login Notifications disabled

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using facebook iOS SDK,

When I call facebook.dialog using a facebook account with Login Notifications disabled, after enter login is entered, it raise the following exception.

`error description: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)"`

UserInfo=0xc2a1d10 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://m.facebook.com/?hasnext#!/dialog/stream.publish?_path=stream.publish&app_id=370118113020066&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&sdk=2&display=touch&link=http%3A%2F%2Fprime31.com&caption&name=Prime31+Studios&picture&api_key=370118113020066&from_login=1&client_id=370118113020066&refid=9, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://m.facebook.com/?hasnext#!/dialog/stream.publish?_path=stream.publish&app_id=370118113020066&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&sdk=2&display=touch&link=http%3A%2F%2Fprime31.com&caption&name=Prime31+Studios&picture&api_key=370118113020066&from_login=1&client_id=370118113020066&refid=9}